# Django ORM - LEFT JOIN with WHERE clause

Tags: django, django-orm, django-1.8

I have made a previous post related to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677459/django-orm-left-join-with-group-by-and-sum) but because this is a related but *new* problem I thought it would be best to make another post for it.

I'm using Django 1.8

I have a User model and a UserAction model. A user has a type. UserAction has a time, which indicates how long the action took as well as a start_time which indicates when the action began. They look like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
   user_type = models.IntegerField()

class UserAction:
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   time = models.IntegerField()
   start_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now what I want to do is get all users of a given type and the sum of time of their actions, optionally filtered by the start_time.

What I am doing is something like this:

```
# stubbing in a start time to filter by
start_time = datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=2)
# stubbing in a type
type = 2
# this gives me the users and the sum of the time of their actions, or 0 if no 
# actions exist
q = User.objects.filter(user_type=type).values('id').annotate(total_time=Coalesce(Sum(useraction__time), 0)
# now I try to add the filter for start_time of the actions to be greater than or # equal to start_time
q = q.filter(useraction__start_time__gte=start_time)
```

Now what this does is of course is an INNER JOIN on UserAction, thus removing all the users without actions. What I really want to do is the equivalent of my LEFT JOIN with a WHERE clause, but for the life of me I can't find how to do that. I've looked at the docs, looked at the source but am not finding an answer. I'm (pretty) sure this is something that can be done, I'm just not seeing how. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks much!

Comment: Do users with no useraction should be included in result?

Comment: @f43d65 - yes they should

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same kind of problem as you. I haven't found any proper way of solving the problem yet, but I've found a few fixes.

- One way would be looping through all the users:

  ```
  q = User.objects.filter(user_type=type)
  for (u in q):
      u.time_sum = UserAction.filter(user=u, start_time__gte=start_time).aggregate(time_sum=Sum('time'))['time_sum']
  ```

  This method does however a query at the database for each user. It might do the trick if you don't have many users, but might get very time-consuming if you have a large database.
- Another way of solving the problem would be using the `extra` method of the QuerySet API. This is a method that is detailed in [this blog post](https://timmyomahony.com/blog/filtering-annotations-django/) by Timmy O'Mahony.

  ```
  valid_actions = UserAction.objects.filter(start_time__gte=start_time)
  q = User.objects.filter(user_type=type).extra(select={
      "time_sum": """
      SELECT SUM(time)
      FROM userAction
      WHERE userAction.user_id = user.id
      AND userAction.id IN %s
      """ % (%s) % ",".join([str(uAction.id) for uAction in valid_actions.all()])
  })
  ```

  This method however relies on calling the database with the SQL table names, which is very un-Django - if you change the `db_table` of one of your databases or the `db_column` of one of their columns, this code will no longer work. It though only requires 2 queries, the first one to get the list of valid `userAction` and the other one to sum them to the matching user.